# Is there an event fired when you travel to a page using this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter().navTo()?

Tags: sapui5

When you navigate to a page using   this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter().navTo("Something") is there an event fired on page something. Is there any way to refresh the page when you navigate to it using this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter().navTo("Something").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [routeMatched](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.routing.Router/events/routePatternMatched) on the target page is going to get hit.

Example:

```
return baseController.extend(
    'XPTO', {
        onInit: function () {


            this.mdRoute = this.getRouter().getRoute('yourRoute');
            this.mdRoute.attachMatched(onRouteOrSubRoutesMatched, this);

        },

    });

 function onRouteOrSubRoutesMatched() {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see the following documentation topics:

- *[Events Fired Centrally by the App or the NavContainer](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/6ec0a7e1d3c64412a673b7dabe28c02b.html)*
- *[Events Fired on the Pages](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/b6ab31cb81bd443996cde2f91d203072.html)*
- [Events for `this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter().getRoute(routeName)`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.routing.Route/events), such as..

  - `beforeMatched`
  - `patternMatched`

Answer (score 0):

```js
return Controller.extend("...", {
  // This is Intial function function called on Page Load
  onInit: function() {
    this._oRouter = UIComponent.getRouterFor(this); // UIComponent required from "sap/ui/core/UIComponent"
    this._oRouter.attachRouteMatched(this.onRouteMatched, this);
  },

  onRouteMatched : function(oEvent) {
    // ...
  },
});
```