# I'm trying to remove event handler with removeEventDelegate but it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, sapui5, event-delegation, removeeventlistener

I'm trying to remove the event handler using the `removeEventDelegate` method but it doesn't work.

This is how I add eventListener:

```js
appointment.addEventDelegate({
    ondragstart: this.myFunction.bind(this, temp)
})
```

This is how I'm trying to remove it but it doesn't work:

```js
appointment.removeEventDelegate({
    ondragstart: this.myFunction.bind(this, temp)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `removeEventDelegate` awaits the same **object** that was passed when calling `addEventDelegate` since the element looks for the object *reference* when removing it (See the [source code](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/71eb06d63c8510d62dc3b56dd8ee73da3f264606/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/core/Element.js#L615-L641)). It doesn't matter whether the functions are new or not.

Below is an example demonstrating removal of an event delegate:

```js
sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(() => sap.ui.require([ "sap/m/ToggleButton" ], ToggleButton => {
  const myDelegate = { // same reference for removing and adding delegate
    onmouseover: () => console.log("mouse hovering"), // e.g.
  };

  const myBtn = new ToggleButton({
    text: "Delegate",
    press: () => !myBtn.getPressed()
      ? myBtn.removeEventDelegate(myDelegate) && console.clear()
      : myBtn.addEventDelegate(myDelegate, this), // `this` should be the controller instance in your case. 
  }).placeAt("content");

}));
console.clear();
```

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" src="https://ui5.sap.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
  data-sap-ui-async="true"
  data-sap-ui-theme="sap_fiori_3"
  data-sap-ui-compatversion="edge"
></script>
<body id="content" class="sapUiBody"></body>
```

Accordingly, you'll have to keep the delegate object somewhere in order to pass it to `removeEventDelegate` later on. See, for example, [stackoverflow.com/a/56852018](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56852018/5846045).

Answer (score 0):

Using `bind` on a `function` creates a **new instance** of that function *every time*. If you don't have a **reference** (a variable/property that points to that instance), there's no way to remove it when used as a listener.

So either assign that instance to a new variable, or just overwrite the function with the bound instance in case you don't want/need any unbound instance:

```
this.myFunction = this.myFunction.bind(this, temp)
// or
this.myBoundFunction = this.myFunction.bind(this, temp);

appointment.addEventDelegate({
    ondragstart: this.myFunction
})


appointment.removeEventDelegate({
    ondragstart: this.myFunction
})
```

Comment: The problem is that this handler is attached to several controls and all of them have different temp value. So i cant store all the references. Any other idea, is there anyway to remove all the handlaers contected to odragstart event?

Comment: Without knowing more of a your code and use-case, I cannot really give advice here. What I said though remains true. Maybe you can push the bound instances into a `this.myBoundFunctions` array and bind/unbind them using the index?